# Convert certificates from txt to CER

Tags: server, ssl-certificate, exchange-server

Hi there I have an exchange server for which I need to renew its Globalsign authority certificate.

After i purchased it I got a zip file with x3 txt files in (password.txt / pem.txt /private key.txt).

Exchange server can only import CER file how can I convert those to CER file ?

[image: exchange]

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the contents of `pem.txt` start with `=====BEGIN CERTIFICATE=====`, you'd either just specify the path of that file, or rename pem.txt to pem.cer (or certificate.cer, or whatever you want to call it).

(And for future reference, taking a screenshot with PrintScr or Alt+PrintScr (just the focused application) and trimming it down in something like paint is better than taking a picture of a monitor)